# Appium: Getting connection error when trying to launch Android server

Tags: java, selenium, appium

Code :
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

```
    File appDirectory = new File("src");
    File app = new File(appDirectory, "Cricbuzz.apk");

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"Android Emulator");

    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, "100");
    capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("Reached before driver");

    WebDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL(
            "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
}
```

}

Note: I have already launched the appium server and the virtual device. I have a confusion whether MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"Android Emulator", refers to the virtual device in general or it should be the exact name of the device.
I ran adb -devices , and got the exact name of the emulator and pasted it, still getting the same error. Appreciate your help in understanding the error.

Error Thrown-

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 02:56:46'
System info: host: 'RAJIT-PC', ip: '10.0.0.65', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:589)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:141)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:160)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:168)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:69)
    at AppTest.main(AppTest.java:31)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:4723 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 02:56:46'
System info: host: 'RAJIT-PC', ip: '10.0.0.65', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:64)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:568)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:4723 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:143)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:134)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:52)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:74)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
    ... 25 more

Comment: It seems your server is not running. Could you restart it and check please

Comment: Yup..........my bad...........I didnt start the server............thanks